# Jenkins - Pipeline access git branch name

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Question:** Is there any way to get the name of the branch that is checkout by the Pipeline in a jenkinsfile?

**NOTE**: I am not in a Multibranch Pipeline!

In my pipeline im using

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
          userRemoteConfigs: [[url:'https://github.com/repo', 
                               credentialsId: 'xxxx',name: '1234']]])
```

where `name` is the commit ID. I need to verify that this commit id is from the branch that a user has specified as parameter (user specifies both branch name and commit id and I need to check if there is no error before building the project).

Why is the branch name not exposed in Pipeline but only in Multibranch Pipeline? Doesn't make sense to me.

There are three reasons why I don't want to convert to the multi branch pipeline:

1. I am using another plugin [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin?focusedCommentId=64684089) in my pipeline that doesn't seem available in the multibranch pipeline.
2. I have a parameterized pipeline, I don't see that option in the multibranch pipeline.
3. A lot of time has gone into this pipeline, I simply don't want to set up this project again from scratch just for this branch name feature.

I have printed out all environment variables, branch name is not among them.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where are you getting the commitid from ??? If it's a hook can you not add the branch name is a parameter ???

Comment: the user specifies the commit he want to get built. Something along the lines `parameters { string(defaultValue: 'develop', description:'', name: '123456')}. This checks out the commit 123456 if the parameter is passed to build the pipeline and develop by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Pipeline: Nodes and Processes, `sh`: Shell Script](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script) :

> **`returnStdout` (optional)**
>
> If checked, standard output from the task is returned as the step value as a `String`, rather than being printed to the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to the log.) You will often want to call `.trim()` on the result to strip off a trailing newline.

and see [git-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> --contains [<commit>]
>       Only list branches which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not specified). Implies `--list`.

Combine these with:

```
...
def branches = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git branch --contains ${commitId}")
...
```

and check whether `branches` contains the branch name given by the user.

BTW, I'd rename your variables since:

- `name` is your commit ID, a.k.a. (commit) hash, so I'd call it `commitId` or `commitHash`
- you actually have some other thing with a name, the *branch*, which can be called `branchName` then to make future maintainers' lifes easier

Comment: One thing I never understood about the `checkout` command in Jenkins. you can either use the key `name`in userRemoteConfigs with either <commitId> or <branchName> as values or you can use the key `branches` to specify the <branchName>. Are you suggesting to define variables `commitId` and `branchName` which are then passed as values to `userRemoteConfig`? I cannot alter the key `name` to something else.

Comment: @tenticon According to "[_`checkout, $class: GitSCM userRemoteConfigs`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#code-checkout-code-general-scm) – `name` –  [is] ID of the repository_", not a hash or branch name and "_`branches` – Nested Object –  `name` – Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a repository._".

Answer (score 11):

if you are using pipeline code I assume you are doing something like:

`checkout scm`

Nice thing is this returns a map with some useful stuff from which you can grab the checked out branch in the following manner:

`def scmVars = checkout scm
 def branchName = scmVars.GIT_BRANCH`

Comment: you hero! <3 Actually nearly everything else didn't work when using pipelines! Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> Why is the branch name not exposed [...]?

see [Git for Computer Scientists](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/):

> `refs`: References, or heads or branches, are like post-it notes slapped on a node in the DAG [Directed Acyclic Graph]. Where as the DAG  only gets added to and existing nodes cannot be mutated, the post-its can be moved around freely. They don't get stored in the history, and they aren't directly transferred between repositories. They act as sort of bookmarks, "I'm working here".

Such it's easy to find a commit from a branch: by walking down from the branch ref through the graph, but it's tricky the other way round since a commit can belong to more than one branch (if the branch is once again branched later). E.g. from [Pro Git, 3.1 Git Branching - Branches in a Nutshell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) where the three commits to the left belong to branches `master` *and* `testing`:

[image]

---

Comment: How does this help me in finding the name of the branch in the jenkins pipeline? sorry if I don't understand the obvious.

Comment: @tenticon Agreed, this doesn't help you in this case. It's an answer with background information to your question "_Why is the branch name not exposed ...?_". Sorry, if that wasn't obvious.